# Avoiding boilerplate with type guards for sub fieflds

Tags: typescript

Assume I have the following types.

```
type Result<T> = Success<T> | Failure

interface Success<T> {
    readonly type: 'Success'
    readonly data: T
}

interface Failure {
    readonly type: 'Failure'
    readonly error: Error
}

function isSuccess<T>(result: Result<T>): result is Success<T> {
    return result.type === 'Success'
}

function isFailure(result: Result<unknown>): result is Failure {
    return result.type === 'Failure'
}
```

Sometimes, I find myself working with some sort of a wrapper (a tuple perhaps) in a collection. And then I tend to want to filter things out and have the type system enforce it, but the following doesn't work.

```
const data: [Result<string>, number][] = []
const filtered = data.filter(it => isSuccess(it[0]))
typeof filtered // It doesn't know that the result is a success
```

And then I end up writing some one off type guard that tests against a tuple type just so the types will narrow. Is there a better way of doing this without having to write those silly little functions? I'm hoping I missed something obvious. The best I can do so far is this.

```
// This works for tuples in general, but I'll need one of these
// for every shape.
export function firstIs<F, T, R extends F>(test: (t: F) => t is R): (it: [F, T]) => it is [R, T] {
    return (it): it is [R, T] => test(it[0])
}

const filtered2 = data.filter(firstIs(isSuccess))
```

[Link to a typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAFQHxQLxQGVEBjYheTHAHygDEBDAS2UQCcIAoDxgO2AlYAzemUIky8CtigBvDlAVR29ACYB7HshBRQkAFxQA5EVLlD8xcvWbtK+sHoGMHAL5de-ISOgNmbaHKKShCqGlo64BAGhr4s7OZBVmHaAqxqrAYAoqxprK5cgog8xMCMGlCM8CYSUlgAFOxIqAZwTejYAJQGjSjAFfBippKUshYK7MBsPMFtAHS60LhLRtVm+RyFxaXllbH+DQi9LYeoaEUA1jxqAO48WF0zvf10THEBY8GTrNM9qPOReGWMVe-nMbi4HGIGngfTsDgMAG1Wr00DDWLwAOZYAA0UB4iAAtgAjAQAXQRpLwUApkOhfUEzE8EBUVLh9FmDNQAjqjD6uBwlVWkh5wARAAZSR0OhwFmpBFBOUyWQB6ZVQACSsLUCB4hj6lxuOgAFvZjdBfn1KlB6FAkEN4BDVVAMEardd0ucBoJ0jpEGBkAgKtMMRAeAJ6MhcUTEH11YZkMg8RBmVANNA5Wb4Jwnd7WFAIAA3ATaeAmyCzDgQAAeYHS9KKJTK0wZrBh6ootFxGFxMHzVf4PBUA1o9X4MIMdWABloHTwOEtAxgDxFiM7zslc4qC+pMC7lMClggX2mIoevOeSL3m7HwBF4sl6yhPBhCsZAmZACZWfZ2YruS223gHkqnEcgpSAA)

Comment: In your example usage, you can change the type of `data` to `[Success<string>, number][]` because the type guard function guarantees that. `typeof` will only return primitive types, and in this case `object` for any array or object.

Comment: The compiler doesn't view `it => isSuccess(it[0])` as a user-defined type guard itself; you'd have to annotate it like `const filtered = data.filter((it): it is [Success<string>, number] => isSuccess(it[0]));`, but that might be the same as "silly little functions" to you; not sure.

Comment: Too bad there's no direct support for [user defined type guards that act on properties](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11796); you can try to rephrase `(x: any) => x[k] is T` as `(x: any) => x is Record<K, T>` but it's hard to write a general-purpose type guard wrapper that does this.  The best version I can come up with ends up narrowing `filtered` to `([Result<string>, number] & Record<0, Success<unknown>)[]` which is a bit too ugly for me to put as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz That does have the advantage of letting me reuse my existing guard. I wouldn't have to make another function that gets executed at runtime, but I don't like solutions that involve manual annotation because it introduces more scope for error. For example, this is fine as far as typescript is concerned: `data.filter((it): it is [Success<string>, number] => isFailure(it[0]))`. Without the annotation, it should have been inferred that the guard casts to a `Failure`, but my annotation really opens me up to some difficult debugging.